# Exception Message: Print only message & Override

Tags: java, exception

Hello i am having a code like this:

```
if(some condition)
    throw Exception("some message");
```

and another one like this:

```
try {    
    something; 
} catch (ArithmeticException e) { 
    throw new Exception ("some other message");
```

I want for each one the messages without the type of exception or any stack trace, classnames etc.

How can i only print the message?

Edit: i cannot use System.out.println, because the message should not be printed in the console. Exception have to be used here.

I need a way to print only own messages.

Comment: in the catch block, print the message, don't re-throw. return a default value

Comment: both code snippets are not related, i edited

Comment: Can return text without throw new, or if you need to return specific exception for example for API, you can return ResponseEntity<String> there use HTTP responses.

Answer (score 0):

for the first one

```
if(some condition)
        System.out.println("some message")
```

and for the second one

```
try {    
    something; 
} catch (ArithmeticException e) { 
    System.out.println("some other message")
```

System.out.println simply prints a message to the console without any stack trace
Also being in a try catch doesn't force you to throw an exception.

Therefore, if you just wanna print a message when something goes wrong (and not throw the exception), do a simple System.out.println

Answer (score 0):

Use: ***e.getMessage()*** to get just the bullet point of the error, or just the ***print*** with whatever You want.

```java
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        try {
          int x = 0;
          // Some condition
          if (x == 1/0) throw new Exception("some condition message");
          // Something
          System.out.println("Something.something()");
        }
        catch (ArithmeticException e) {
          System.out.println("ArithmeticException Message: ");
          System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("Exception Message");
          System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ArithmeticException Message: 
/ by zero
```